# Was Wolfgang Unzicker the last Amateur GM?

Tags: grandmaster

[Wolfgang Unzicker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Unzicker) was a German GM, rated about 2550 and worked as a judge. In the sense of holding down a job while playing, he was an "amateur" player.

So was Unzicker, a GM in the 70's, the last amateur GM?

Comment: Most GM's have a "real" job, very few make their living solely from chess.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The economist [Ken Rogoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Rogoff#Chess) (b. 1953) achieved the GM title in 1978, but was never a "professional" chess player. Rogoff is currently a professor of economics at Harvard University.

Comment: In the absence of better answers that are true "amateur" GMs I am going to tick this.

Answer (score 33):

> So in the sense of holding down a job while playing he was an
>   "amateur" player.
>
> So was Unzicker, a GM in the 70's, the last amateur GM?

No. Here are 4 current British "amateur" grandmasters.

- English GM Matthew Turner is a teacher at Millfield School in Somerset.
- English GM Matthew Sadler is a computer consultant in the Netherlands.
- English GM Luke McShane (currently on [4/7 in the Netanya Masters](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/netanya-masters-2019/7/1/1)) is a financial trader in London
- Scottish GM Dr. Jonathan Rowson is Director of the Social Brain Centre at the Royal Society of Arts in London

Answer (score 12):

There are plenty of GMs that do not play professionally, e.g. GM [Luke McShane is a financial trader](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2017/jul/14/luke-mcshane-shares-third-consecutive-title), GM [Hou Yifan is a Rhodes scholar](https://www.bsg.ox.ac.uk/people/yifan-hou). So if your definition of "amateur" is holding down a job while playing occasionally, Wolfgang Unzicker certainly was not the last amateur GM.

Comment: But I think you have fallen into a subtle trap there. They are GMs whose broad intent is to play chess only. Or to put it another way, their life is variable; Hou Yifan may come back after she does her studies.

Comment: @athornton I don't see how that's relevant. They're holding down a job while playing, making them amateurs.

Comment: Also Georg Meier, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NSzG0BGfO8 (1:45).

Comment: I think the more important question is, did they _ever_ play professionally?  Do they hold other jobs because chess was never anything more than a serious hobby, or simply because professional chess didn't pay the bills?

Comment: If that's what the OP wants to ask, he/she should clarify that in the question.